# C program in Git Bash does not accept input properly

Tags: c, cmd, git-bash

I am trying to run my C program in Git Bash but it doesn't seem to accept inputs as expected and as it does in Windows Command Prompt.

This is my simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char nom[10];
    printf("Enter you name: ");
    gets(nom);
    printf("Your name is %s.", nom);
    return 0;
}
```

This is a screenshot from Git Bash:

[image: screenshot]

This is a screenshot form CMD:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Stop using `gets()`. It is dangerous. It is not part of the C Standard (removed in 2011).

Comment: your environments deal with buffering differently: probably one is unbuffered, the other is line buffered. To have the output show up immediately in the line buffered environment, add `fflush(stdout);` after the relevant prints (this does not harm the unbuffered environment), or terminate the prints with a newline: `printf("...\n", ...);`